# Creating very custom AJAX request

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, web

I'm pretty new to javascript-web interaction, so any wide advice would be helpful.

Example of what I need:

```
POST Join HTTP/1.1
Host: my.host
Content-Type: myContentType

[message body]
```

Trying to do that with AJAX and see result in Charles web proxy. The result is not that good, since ajax adds so many fields that I don't require and don't gives me access to set Content-Type by hand (or at least I haven't found the way).

Server is very sensitive to all symbols in header, so I think I need a very smart way to construct those requests by hand (?) or with a really tuneable system. Maybe anyone could help me on this.

Comment: [ajax.setRequestHeader()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#setRequestHeader()) for setting the content-type. I don't think you can **remove** headers.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159166/removing-http-headers-from-an-xmlhttprequest

Answer (score 3):

You should have a look at the documentation on `XMLHttpRequest`. Methods like `.setRequestHeader()` or `overrideMimeType()` might be interesting for you.

[See MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#setRequestHeader%28%29).